# When does your health get automatically refilled?

Tags: the-last-of-us

Between some chapters, Joel's health gets automatically refilled. Which ones?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the protagonist's health gets restored after each cut-scene. For example, the part where Joel meets Marlene for the first time, it is a fairly long cut-scene. His health should fully restore after it.

However, his health will not refill after every chapter, because some of the transitions between chapters is while you are moving in the game. That's why I always play it safe, trying to keep health above 25% all the time.

I've completed the game 2 times and also completed the additional DLC, with Ellie's backstory. So, if you need any help, just ask.

Hope this helped.